Java Android OnKeyListener Event not triggered
I am trying to detect, when a user adds more then a specific amount (20) of letters in a Text field. When typing the the field itemNo, the debugger will not get triggered in the onKey Event. But when clicking on the save button (setOnTouchListener), this works perfectly.
What am i missing here?
Thanks for your advice.
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    if (binding == null) {
        binding = FragmentItemBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        binding.itemNo.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (binding.itemNo.getEditText().length() > 20) {   //This Code is unreached, when text entered
                    binding.itemNo.getEditText().setText("");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        binding.save.setOnTouchListener(new SimpleSwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouchUp(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (binding.itemNo.getEditText().length() > 20)     //This Code is reached, when the button is pressed
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return binding.getRoot();
}


The onKey event listener may not be the best choice for detecting changes in the text field because it is specifically for key events and might not cover all scenarios of text input.
A more reliable approach would be to use a TextWatcher to monitor changes in the text field.
You can try the below function. This is converted code from kotlin to Java. You should update as per your requirement.
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    if (binding == null) {
        binding = FragmentItemBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
      }

        binding.itemNo.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // No action is needed before text changes
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() > 20) {
                    binding.itemNo.getEditText().setText("");
                    // Move the cursor to the end of the text
                    binding.itemNo.getEditText().setSelection(0);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // No action is needed after text changes
            }
        });

        binding.save.setOnTouchListener(new SimpleSwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouchUp(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (binding.itemNo.getEditText().length() > 20) {
                    return false;
                }
                // Add your save logic here
                return true;
            }
        });
    
    return binding.getRoot();
}

